# Meteor {{#each}} – conditional formatting per item

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I've got a cursor taken form the database and I'm doing the usual ‘list every item’ using {{#each}} helper tag.

html

```
{{#each item}}
  <span class="label">{{this}}</span>
{{/each}}
```

js

```
Template.name.helpers({
  item: function() {
    return Session.get('foo').items
  },
});
```

However, since each item belongs to one of *n* classes, I would like to a) determine which one it is and b) change the `span` class accordingly.

In other words, the names of the categories are coupled with strings that I now get in place of `{{this}}` and stored in a separate collection, e.g.

```
{
  "_id": "whatnot"
  "item": "item1",
  "category": "bar"
}
```

and the objective is to compare them and determine the class matching the category:

```
{{#each item}}
  <span class="[[what "category" does ‘this’ belong to?]]">{{this}}</span>
{{/each}}
```

If this is impossible or a bad way to do this, I'd appreciate any tips for better architecture because I think that might be the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with your helpers:

HTML:

```
<template name="name">
  {{#each item}}
    {{> item}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="item">
  <span class="{{category}}">{{this}}</span>
</template>
```

js

```
Template.name.helpers({
  item: function(){
    return Session.get('foo').items
  }
});

Template.item.helpers({
  category: function(){
    return Categories.findOne({_id: this.categoryId}).category;
  }
});
```

This assumes that your *Items* collection links to the *Categories* collection via a key called *categoryId* - your collection names and keys are probably different. It also assumes that you have css classes setup for your possible category names.

You might think "Gee, I have to run a search every time I display an item?" and the answer is "Yes, but minimongo is really really fast so don't fret that." You're searching in memory on the client, not over the network to the server to disk.

Normally your *item* helper would return a cursor, ex: `Items.find(query)` but it looks like you're executing the find and stuffing it into a session variable elsewhere. You might be able to get rid of that extra step.

Comment: And I'll add my almost standard comment about looking at [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) if you're doing things that feel like relational joins.

Comment: Splendid help, thank you very much! Though for some reason I've had to do some adjustments based on trial and error, notably this: `Categories.findOne({"my_id": this.toString()}).category` I'm indeed executing the find elsewhere because I'm feeding it to `aslagle/reactive-table` and then displaying these items based on which row is clicked so the above is just a minimal example. I'll try to figure it out and edit my post for future reference but right now I'm just happy it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way of doing this is to go directly to the collection.

1. Set your session var to the query you're going to execute on the collection (not sure if this is even necessary, it looks like you may just be saving the result of a query to the session var?)
2. Execute the collection query in a helper
3. `#each` over the cursor

This is nice because now instead of wonder wtf `{{this}}` is in a month, you'll have `{{items}}`. Second, you'll have the category in your data context, so you can write a helper for it. For example, if you want all `bar` category items to have a `baz` class:

`return (this.category === 'bar') && 'baz'`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm not sure I understand. It may have not been clear that I've got two separate collections, one of which contains items and the other one categories that they belong to and I need to match them by values. Could you please explicitly state which one do you mean in each step? Apologies for being daft but I only started with Meteor and in fact most of JS two days ago.

Comment: Ah, didn't know it was 2 collections. Consider denormalizing & sticking the category in the item collection. In NoSQL, denormalizing, especially if it's just 1 field, is almost always the right choice. In doing so, you get easier queries, you don't need to subscribe to a 2nd collection, etc.

Comment: My bad, I should have been more explicit, sorry! Thanks for the tip, I'll have a look at denormalisation as well. I'm also new to Mongo so it'll take a while but I need the second collection for another part of the application – think of the two as posts and users, for example, plus one of them is being updated by an external scraper so it's a bit of mess.